# Detect and read log file changes with Logstash automatically

Tags: docker, logging, logstash, elastic-stack

I've been working for the last week in a centralized logging solution using the ELK Stack.

The environment I'm currently using is basically 4 containers with Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana and Logspout. I'm collecting logs with logstash using the file input with a shared volume on my local machine.

The logstash configuration file I'm currently using goes like this (logstash.sample.conf):

```
input {


file {
    path => "/share-logs/lumen.log"
    stat_interval => 1
    type => applumen
    #sincedb_path => "/share-logs/lumen.log.sincedb"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null" 
  }
  file{
    path => "/share-logs/laravel.log"
    type => applaravel
    #sincedb_path => "/share-logs/laravel.log.sincedb"
    stat_interval => 1
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null" 
  }
  file {
    path =>"/share-logs/server.log"
    type => appjava
    #sincedb_path => "/share-logs/server.log.sincedb"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null" 
  }
  file
  {
    path => "/share-logs/access.log"
    type => apacheaccess
    #sincedb_path => "/share-logs/access.log.sincedb"
    stat_interval => 1
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null" 
  }
  file
  {
    path => "/share-logs/error.log"
    type => apacheerror
    #sincedb_path => "/share-logs/error.log.sincedb"
    stat_interval => 1
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null" 
  }
  tcp {
    port => 5000
    type => syslog
  }
  udp {
    port => 5000
    type => syslog
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "(?:%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}|-) +(?:%{HOSTNAME:containerId}|-) +(?:%{NOTSPACE:containerName}|-) +(?:%{WORD:processId}|-) %{GREEDYDATA:logMsg}" } #Still needs to parse with multi-line features
    }
  }
  if [type] == "applumen" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOG5424SD:timestamp} %{WORD:application}.%{WORD:logType}:%{GREEDYDATA:logMsg}" }
    }
    multiline {
      pattern => "(Stack trace:)|(^#.+)|(^\"\")|(  thrown+)|(^\s)"
      what    => "previous"
    }
  }
  if [type] == "applaravel" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOG5424SD:timestamp} %{WORD:application}.%{WORD:logType}:%{GREEDYDATA:logMsg}" }
    }
    multiline {
      pattern => "(Stack trace:)|(^#.+)|(^\"\")|(  thrown+)|(^\s)|(Next )|(^\n)"
      what    => "previous"
    }
    multiline {
      pattern => "(^\n)"
      negate => "true"
      what => "previous"
    }
  }
  if [type] == "appjava" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{NOTSPACE:logType} +%{NOTSPACE:service} %{GREEDYDATA:logMsg}"}
    }
    multiline {
      pattern => "(default task-)|( at)|(user.)"
      what => "previous"
    }
    multiline {
      pattern => "(^\n)"
      negate => "true"
      what => "previous"
    }
  }
  if [type] == "apacheaccess"{
    grok {
      match => {"message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG:logMsg}"}
    }
  }
  if [type] == "apacheerror"{
    grok {
      match => {"message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:logMsg}"}
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { host => "elasticsearch" }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Right now if I change a line in any log file manually or by the application in any of the mentioned files Logstash will detect the changes and immediately send them to Elasticsearch.

What is happening is that the server.log (Java application) is not being tracked the same way as the others and the configuration is pretty much the same.

Am I doing anything wrong here?